# Capybara gives "Attempt to select disabled option: -1" when selecting an option

Tags: select, drop-down-menu, selenium-webdriver, capybara

I want to select an option from dropdown but it gives the following error, even I can select it manually:

> Attempt to select disabled option: -1

```
irb#1(main):078:0> select "S", :match => :first, :from => "level2"
Attempt to select disabled option: -1
=> nil
irb#1(main):079:0> select "M", :match => :first, :from => "level2"
=> nil
```

This error is given for the every option[1] and option[0] is label of drop-down, for this case "S" is not selectable but "M" and others are.

```
<div id="sizeDiv">
   <select class="form-control tooltip_sizes" id="level2" level="2" name="size" data-msg-required="Beden seçimi yapınız" data-rule-required="true">
      <option value="-1" level="2" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Beden Seçenekleri</option>
      <option class="s" level="2" value="31884" available="1">S</option>
      <option class="m" level="2" value="31894" available="1">M</option>
      <option class="l" level="2" value="31893" available="1">L</option>
      <option class="xl" level="2" value="31945" available="1">XL</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

My question is why I cant select option[1] and how to select it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using :match => :first and by default substring matches are acceptable your select "S" is matching a substring in "Seçenekleri", attempting to select the first option in the select which is disabled, and hence returning an error.  You have a couple of options to get what you want - remove the :match => :first option from your call (and why do you want match: :first in this find anyway?) which will then go back to the default of :smart which attempts an exact match first and if none will then do a substring match.  Otherwise you could add the exact: true option which will limit the find only to exact matches

Comment: oh I see it. Thanks a lot.